# The with-method is not working on objects in traits

Tags: grails, groovy

This one has been bothering me for a while.

It seems like it's impossible to use the with-method in a trait.

Example:

```
class P {
    int prop
}

trait T {
    P pogo = new P().with {
        prop = 42 // MissingPropertyException: No such property: prop for class: C
        return it
    }
}

class C implements T {
}

def pogo = new C().pogo
assert pogo.prop == 42
```

Can anyone explain why that is?

The code is borrowed from [this old thing](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/groovy-branch-master-updated-GROOVY-9386-traits-do-not-transform-dynamic-variable-within-closure-td5770958.html).

Comment: This works with groovy 3.0.8

Comment: @cfrick wow, you'er right! 

It doesn't work with 2.5.x or 3.0.4 - but it works fine with 3.0.8 (latest). I must patiently wait for a Grails version that will work with 3.0.8 or higher then :sad_panda:

Comment: I'd imagine, that a grails version using 3.0.x would still be fine to force 3.0.y. Have you tried using an explicit `it` as suggested in the anwer? Side note: those newer groovy versions also have `tap` instead of the `.with{ ... return it}` pattern (but i doubt that this will help here)

Comment: Yeah, I know that `it`works, but that kind of defies the purpose. And nope, `tap` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

(Comment, but need answer formatting.)

It needs to be `it.prop = 42`, although I don't recall why.

Maybe because `C` hasn't been fully constructed yet? It's been awhile.

```
trait T {
  P pogo = new P().with {
    it.prop = 42
    return it
  }
}

def pogo = new C().pogo
println(pogo.prop)
assert pogo.prop == 42

def c = new C()
c.pogo.prop = 12
assert c.pogo.prop == 12
```